Fire base fire store query not returning posts after creating required index in react app
I'm developing a React application using Firebase Firestore as the backend. I have a component designed to fetch posts based on their createdAt timestamp in show them in descending order
I would like to add a function that removes the post from the home page(my feed posts) when user marked the items as sold.
However,I received an error:

Error The query contains range and inequality filters on multiple fields, please refer to the documentation for index selection best practices

Then I follow the link it it’s create the missing index but when I try to run my code the same error occurs
Here is my code to fetch the posts:
const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const postCollection = collection(firestore, "posts");
      // Exclude posts with a status of 'sold'
      const postsQuery = query(postCollection, orderBy("createdAt", "desc"), where("status", "!=", "sold"));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(postsQuery);
      const postsData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      dispatch(setProduct(postsData));
    } catch (error) {
      showToast("Error", error.message, "error");
      console.error("Error fetching posts: ", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

How I change the status
const handleStatusChange = async (newStatus) => {
    setPostStatus(newStatus);
    const postDocRef = doc(firestore, "posts", id);
    try {
        await updateDoc(postDocRef, { status: newStatus });
        showToast("Success", "Post status updated successfully", "success");
    } catch (error) { 
        console.error("Error updating post status:", error);
        showToast("Error", "Failed to update post status", "error");
    }
};

My button to change the status:
   <Button
        borderRadius={0}
         w={"full"}
        colorScheme={postStatus === 'sold' ? "red" : "blue"}
        size={"sm"}
        fontSize={14}
        disabled={postStatus === 'sold'} // Disable button if the post is sold
        >
  {postStatus === 'sold' ? "Sold" : "Buy now"}
</Button>


it's originally supposed to show a list of products like this:

However after adding the index in firebase and refreshing nothing shows up where the post is supposed to be
I double-checked the Firestore console to ensure the index was created successfully.(although every time i navigate to the link it ask me to create the index again)
I verified that there are indeed posts in the database with status set to "available" and valid createdAt timestamps.
I made sure there are no additional console errors that might indicate what's going wrong.
Why might the query still fail to return any posts after the index has been created and the error resolved? What steps can I take to debug or fix this issue so that the posts properly appear in my React application?
[![index in firestore][4]][4]

Adding an index should in no way change the results of any query.  Adding an index simply makes certain queries possible that require the added index.  Are you saying that removing the index makes your query work again?

That seems only part of the error message. It should tell you something about a missing index too. Is that indeed the case?
"The query contains multiple inequality fields, please refer to the documentation for index selection best practices: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/multiple-inequalities. The query requires an index. You can create it here:
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/%s/firestore/indexes?create_composite=<base64_encoded_index_def>"

If so, can you include the link from that error message in the question? And also a screenshot of the index in the Firestore console (as that seems to be missing now)?
